# How to display data from normal HTML table to Angular Material Table? i want exact my HTML into mat table html.!

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular5, material-design

THIS IS MY TS FILE

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { RecommendationService } from '../recommendation-service.service';
    import { CustomHttpService } from 'app/services/custom-http.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-opportunity',
      templateUrl: './opportunity.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./opportunity.component.scss'],
      providers: [RecommendationService]

    })
    export class OpportunityComponent implements OnInit {


      resData: any = [];
      keys: any;
      show: boolean;

      constructor(private recommendationService: RecommendationService) {
        this.recommendationService.viewData().subscribe(resViewData => {
          this.resData = resViewData;
          this.keys = Object.keys(resViewData[0])

        });
      }

      toggle() {
        this.show = !this.show
      }
      ngOnInit() {

      }
```

```html
<--! THIS IS MY HTML-->

<table *ngIf='show'>

        <th *ngFor="let res of keys"> 
      <!-- passing data into function-->
      {{res}}
          <div *ngFor="let schedule_data of resData">
            {{schedule_data[res]}}
          </div>
        </th>

      </table>
```

```
   [![THIS IS MY RESULT][1]][1]
```

```html
This is my JSON

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Beispiel"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Sample"
    }
]
```

**

i want to dispay this table data from normal html to angular material
as im getting data from local json and displaying  data 
please help!

so it possible to make normal html to angular mat table
could please tell me how to make mat table.
im mostly confused in how to make header in angular mat table and how to display rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without creating an Interface also, here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5r1fh7?file=app/table-basic-example.ts) example

In `app.module.ts`:

```
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
```

Add this module in imports array:

```
imports: [MatTableModule]
```

Changes in TS file:

```
ELEMENT_DATA: any[] = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: "Test"
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: "Beispiel"
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Name: "Sample"
    }
];
displayedColumns: string[] = ['Id', 'Name'];
dataSource = this.ELEMENT_DATA;
```

And in HTML file:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Id}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks but my table having dynamic data i don't know about my column name please check my html for that so please could make that my html into mat table html! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Material Spec](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). You can do the following:

**EDIT** for dynamic data

component.ts

```
resData: any = [];
keys: any;
```

component.html

```
<table *ngIf="resData.length > 0" mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8 table-content" [dataSource]="resData">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let currentCol of keys; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{ currentCol }}">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ currentCol }}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let rowIndex = index">{{
      element[colIndex] }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="keys"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: keys;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks but my table having dynamic data  i dont know about my column name please check my html for that!